# POSIX - pthread_kill()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Why this thread continue its execution though I kill it??

```
pthread_t pid;
pthread_create(&pid, NULL, (func)countdown, NULL);
pthread_kill(pid, 1);
pthread_join(pid, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pthread_kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) is a function for sending signals to a thread. You are currently sending it the signal `1`, which is `SIGHUP`. The standard signals for requesting or forcing termination are `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`, which are `15` and `9` respectively.

Also, you should be using constants and not magic numbers to send signals. These are defined in `signal.h`. The [signal documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/signal.h.html) will give you more details.

Update: Per nos's comment, the correct way to terminate threads (and not the entire application) is to use [`pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). The usage of `pthread_kill` I described above will tend to kill the entire process, assuming the receiving thread does not register a signal handler.

Comment: The way to terminate threads is with pthread_cancel, not pthread_kill (but even that needs great care). With pthread_kill, if the action is to terminate, the whole process is terminated, not just the thread.

Comment: Yes, `pthread_cancel` is the `proper` way to cancel a POSIX thread but I'd wager to say the `correct` way to 'cancel' a thread is with a conditional object of some sort (either a `pthread_cond` type or just a simple `bool` or `int`) that gets checked in the thread ... canceling a thread (in POISX or Windows) can have possible negative effects on your application as well as lead to possible stack corruption issues (though you may get lucky most of the time and not 'see' these errors).